# How do you change the equalisation of an individual song/audio?

Tags: audio, sound, frequency, equalizer, editor

I've been looking for weeks, and I have nowhere else to turn to. I really thought this would be very simple to find, but I'm looking for any type of software that has a 5 band equaliser, that allows me to edit a song I've created. I'm looking for specifically a 5 band that has 60 Hz, 230 Hz, 910 Hz, 3600 Hz, 14000 Hz. Nothing other than that, just that. Everything I find is for either my entire phone device, or my pc, and doesn't let me alter a specific song/file. When I do find ones that can alter specific songs, they're either not 5 Band, and if they are 5 band for some reason they're not "60 hz, 230 hz, 910 hz, 3600 hz, 14000 hz".

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this, but if anyone can help me out, you'd be helping me so much, I've literally lose days and days of sleep over this.

Comment: Sounds like the OCD is kicking in big-time! Answer below is what you need. Put the song into a DAW, apply the parametric and then export the version you have effectively re-mastered. You will note that when you change headphones the spectral content will change so you don't want to end up chasing your tail on this.

Comment: The number of albums I've remastered for personal use over the years because I don't like how they were done in the first place. Though I fully expect someone will have returned the favour at some point on albums I **did** master in the first place…  ;))

Answer (score 2):

The way it’s worded it might not be suitable but I’ll give it a shot anyway.

What you want is a 5 band parametric equalizer. 
There are plenty of DAWs that have them.

A fully parametric equalizer (PEQ as it may be called in a DAW) lets you move any band to any position between 20Hz and 20kHz

Answer (score 0):

iTunes allows you to apply equalization per song: 
1. create a custom EQ setting,
2. in Song Info, add this custom EQ to your song.

The iTunes EQ is a 10-band graphic EQ. Almost any graphic EQ will not have bands centered on the frequencies you want. The standard is to center on 1K, or multiples/divisions of 1K. You need a parametric EQ to get the center frequencies you want.

But I agree with Timinycricket, you should edit the source file once instead of applying the EQ on playback.